# Parse error on a data type I defined

Tags: haskell, types

I'm trying to make a card game in Haskell

I defined the following data types

```
data Rank = R2 | R3 | R4 | R5 | R6 | R7 | R8 | R9 | R10 | J | Q | K | A
deriving (Bounded, Enum, Eq, Ord)

data Suit = S | H | D | C
deriving (Bounded, Enum, Eq, Ord, Show)

data Card = Card { rank :: Rank, suit :: Suit }
deriving (Eq, Ord)

type Deck = [Card]
```

I am then trying to define a constant for a full deck of cards as such:

```
fullDeck :: Deck
fullDeck   = [
              Card{R2,S}..........
```

with plenty more cards behind that for every card in the deck
When I try to compile this I get the error "Parse error on input R2"
I however defined R2 as part of the Rank data type, and I am unsure as to why it is not correctly working

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are mixing positional and field notation. Either use:

```
Card R2 S
```

or

```
Card{rank=R2, suit=S}
```

The expression:

```
Card{R2,S}
```

is not valid.

---

There is a [`NamedFieldPuns`](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.2.1/html/users_guide/syntax-extns.html#record-puns) extension that would allow you to write something similar to what you wrote. In particular it allows things like:

```
aCard = Card{rank,suit}
  where
    rank = R2
    suit = S
```

instead of:

```
aCard = Card{rank=rank, suit=suit}
  where
    rank = R2
    suit = S
```

however, in this case you *must* use the name of the fields, so that the compiler is able to infer which fields you want to fill.

The extension also allows to avoid repetition in the patterns too:

```
f (Card{rank, suit}) = ...
```

instead of:

```
f (Card{rank=rank, suit=suit}) = ...
```

which is the syntax you must use without the extension enabled.

Answer (score 3):

That's because `fullDeck` should be like this:

```
fullDeck :: Deck
fullDeck   = [ Card R2 S, Card R6 C ]
```

You can play around on ghci:

```
λ> let a = Card R2 S
λ> a
a :: Card
λ> let b = Card {R2, S}
parse error on input `R2'
λ> let b = Card {rank = R2, suit = S}
λ> b
b :: Card
```